# How docker container can communicate in PCF

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cloud-foundry, pcf

I have multiple docker containers. In local they talk to each other using network and compose.yml. I have pushed my containers to PCF only i don't know how to make them talk to each other. Can anyone help me out??

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you would utilize Cloud Foundry's container to container networking to do this.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/understand-cf-networking.html

By default, no connections are allowed between containers but you can use the `cf` cli to allow connections on specific ports between your applications.  Your applications just need to be configured to start and listen on the ports that you allow.

While it's not docker specific, there's a good example here.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-networking-examples/blob/master/docs/c2c-no-service-discovery.md

Using docker should be minimally different.  You'll obviously need to create your own docker images and make sure that those are going to listen on the correct ports, otherwise it's just an adjustment to how you push the application (i.e. pass the docker image name to `cf push`).  The `cf add-network-policy` commands should be the same.

Hope that helps!

** **UPDATE** **

If you are looking for `docker-compose` like behavior, kind of a run one command and deploy multiple apps, you can achieve this with `cf push` and a manifest.yml file.

The manifest.yml file allows you to define multiple applications. Thus you can use it to deploy a series of applications that work together, like you often see with `docker-compose`.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html

You have quite a bit of flexibility with manifest.yml, you can deploy buildpack based apps or docker image based apps. You can configure routes, bound services, health checks, memory/disk quotas, and if you're on a new enough version, even processes and sidecars. That said, it can't do 100% of what you can with the cf cli, for example you cannot control the above mentioned network policy using a manifest.yml. If you need to control something not exposed through manifest.yml, the other option would be to script the deployment.

Comment: Thanks Daniel but as you said it is not docker specific. I was thinking of something like docker-compose that not only create network for all services but also have options like link and stuff. The method you just told is applicable for any application inside PCF but is there some compose like facility for docker on PCF

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your use case.  Maybe you can explain more.  All I can say is to reiterate that there's nothing docker specific you need to do.  If you want to communicate between apps running on PCF (any apps), you just use the network policy commands to allow access between them.  It doesn't matter if it's a docker app or a buildpack based app or some new app type thats added in the future.  It's all the same.

Comment: Hey @DanielMikusa were you able to achieve docker-compose in cloud foundry?

Comment: @ChetanHireholi Sorry, not sure what you mean. `docker-compose` is a completely separate tool from Cloud Foundry. Can you expand on what you're looking for here?

Comment: @DanielMikusa Thanks for replying. I understand that both are totally different tools, I was looking for ways to do a "docker-compose up" in Cloud Foundry.

Comment: If you want behavior that's like `docker-compose`, you can use `cf push` and a manifest.yml file. Posting an update above about this option.